# Wrap text within #id>span in href

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

[Here](http://www.jokerleb.com/ads/boat/), it's Wordpress, I can't edit the html, I have to use Jquery or Javascript, I have the following

```
   <li id="cp_phone_number" class=""><span>Phone Number:</span> 71471772</li>
```

How to make it, so when You click on the phone number, it opens the dialer on your phone? If there's a better way let me know, the phone number should be a variable

```
<li id="cp_phone_number" class=""><span>Phone Number:</span><a href="tel:+96171471772">+96171471772</a></li>
```

And if the phone number starts with `00` or `+` then don't add `+961` because the user has entered the country code. I tried using Jquery `wrap`but I don't know how to navigate the dom. I can't get to it using

```
var phone = $("#cp_phone_number > span").text(); // nor .html()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$("#cp_phone_number > span").text();` will return `Phone Number:`. You want `$("#cp_phone_number > a").text();`

EDIT: sorry, didn't read the question correct. Im not deleting this because of the comments

EDIT 2: you want this: http://jsfiddle.net/2sjvf8wq/

Comment: still undefined

Comment: can you try `console.log($("#cp_phone_number"));`

Comment: I guess the problem is that the number is after closing the span and in between quotes